# Not able to start thin server

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3.2, thin

I am Using thin server(thin (1.5.0)) and trying to start server with command **thin start** , which was running fine earlier But now gives me below error:(I dont Remember what wrong i have done which cause this error now) Error:

```
    trunk$ thin start
    /usr/bin/thin:5:in `require': no such file to load -- thin (LoadError)
from /usr/bin/thin:5
```

I am using ruby 1.8.7 .Please Help me with this its almost killing me. Trying to Resolve since 2 days. Thanks in Advance for any Help..
I guess this is happening after i tried to install rvm 1.8.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted out the problem.. All i have done is I just Rebuild my all gems with following command

```
     gem pristine --all
```

And all error has resolved, I guess when server is not able to load gem, Its better to rebuild gem which can sort out all error.